# How to merge two plots in Python?

Tags: python, merge, triangulation, delaunay, world-map

My aim is to plot some data and merge it with the world map. I produce data using Delaunay triangulation, like this:

```
u = np.array(lat)
v = np.array(lon)
x = u
y = v
z = np.array(iwv)
tri = Delaunay(np.array([u,v]).T)
plt.tricontourf(y, x, z, lev, triangles=tri.simplices)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I also make a map using mpl_toolkits:

```
from mpl_toolkits.basemap import Basemap
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat= 35,urcrnrlat=60,llcrnrlon=0,urcrnrlon=30,resolution='c', suppress_ticks=True)
m.drawcountries()
m.drawcoastlines()
plt.show()
```

These procedures give me two consequtive separated pictures with the results of triangulation and the map. How can I merge them and get picture with both map and result of triangulation?
Thank you in advance.

To armatita.
Thank you for your answer, but it doesn't help. When I run this code:

```
u = np.array(lat)
v = np.array(lon)
x = u
y = v
z = np.array(iwv)
tri = Delaunay(np.array([u,v]).T)
lev = np.linspace(0, 0.1, 100)
m = Basemap(projection='merc',llcrnrlat= 35,urcrnrlat=60,llcrnrlon=0,urcrnrlon=30,resolution='c', suppress_ticks=True)
m.drawcountries()
m.drawcoastlines()
plt.tricontourf(y, x, z, lev, triangles=tri.simplices)
plt.colorbar()
plt.show()
```

I get just an empty map with color bar.

To dl.meteo:
Thank you, but when I'm trying to do that, I get the next message:

```
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File
> "/home/anton/PycharmProjects/final/test.py", line 76, in <module>
>     plot = m.contourf(x1, y1,z, lev)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line
> 521, in with_transform
>     return plotfunc(self,x,y,data,*args,**kwargs)   File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/mpl_toolkits/basemap/__init__.py", line
> 3644, in contourf
>     xx = x[x.shape[0]/2,:] IndexError: too many indices
```

As I understand, the third argument in contourf() should be a 2D-array, but triangulation returns 1D-array.

Comment: You have two instances of plt.show(), remove the first and run the plot instructions sequentially (so one after the other). Once all instructions are done (for both plots), do plt.show()

Answer (score 0):

You have to reference m (map) to your variables x and y .

```
x,y = m(lats,lons)
```

and then you have to initialize the contour

```
plot = m.contour(x,y)
```

I hope this helps, i am a beginner too ;)